# WHERE returning too many rows for data NOT BETWEEN two dates

Tags: mysql, datetime

I want to return data that is not between current date and the last 7 days.

My SELECT statement appears ok, but it is also returning the current day's data.

```
SELECT
    customer.id AS id,
    customer.customer_id AS customer_id,
    customer.name AS name,
    customer.phone1 AS phone1,
    customer.location_area AS location_area,
    sales.post_date AS post_date 
FROM 
    sales
INNER JOIN 
    customer
ON 
    sales.customer_id = customer.customer_id
WHERE 
    post_date 
NOT BETWEEN 
   CAST( DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS DATE )
AND 
   CAST( NOW() AS DATE )
ORDER BY 
   sales.id 
DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Please note the customer_id field used in the ON clause is not a primary key in any of the two referenced tables.

What might be missing in my query?

Comment: obvious but necessary question - is "post_date" a datetime field (and not varchar or something)? If not you may need to cast it before doing the comparison

Comment: @ADyson, th 'post_date' field is a datetime field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is usually confusion about the different meanings of  `DATE` datatypes on the one hand and `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` data types on the other.

Let's say `NOW()` is `1-April-2017 09:35`. And, let's say you have a row in your `sales` table with a `post_date` value of `1-April-2017 08:20`. Let's say your `post_date` column has the data type `DATETIME`.

Then your WHERE clause looks like this after values are applied.

```
WHERE '2017-04-01 08:20' NOT BETWEEN CAST( '2017-03-25 09:35' AS DATE )
                                 AND CAST( '2017-04-01 09:35' AS DATE )
```

Applying the `CAST` operations, we get.

```
WHERE '2017-04-01 08:20' NOT BETWEEN '2017-03-25'
                                 AND '2017-04-01'
```

Finally, when comparing a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` to a `DATE` value, the `DATE` value is interpreted as having a time of midnight. So your query looks like this:

```
WHERE '2017-04-01 08:20' NOT BETWEEN '2017-03-25 00:00:00'
                                 AND '2017-04-01 00:00:00'
```

And, guess what? `'2017-04-01 08:20'` is **after** `'2017-04-01 00:00:00'`.

What you need is this:

```
WHERE 
 NOT (
            post_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY --on or after midnight 2016-3-25
        AND post_date <  CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY --before midnight 2016-04-02
     )
```

Please notice that this expression encompasses eight days total.

You can't use `BETWEEN` for this kind of comparison because you need `<` for the end of the range, and `BETWEEN` uses `<=` for the ends of all its ranges.

Also, `CURDATE()` is much easier to read than `CAST(NOW() AS DATE)`.